# HttpURLConnection object returned from method does not work - headers are not added

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have a class with a number of methods that make different HTTP requests that share headers in common. I would therefore like to have a method that adds the common headers to avoid duplicate code. Here is an example of a method I have tried to use:

```
public static HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url, String authorization) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.addRequestProperty(AUTHORIZATION, authorization);
    return connection;

}
```

If I use this method as follows:

```
            connection = getConnection(url, authorization);
```

It does not work and gives response code 500 (Internal Server Error).

However, if I add the headers without using the getConnection() method like this:

```
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.addRequestProperty(AUTHORIZATION, authorization);
```

It works and gives response code 200 (OK).

It gave the response back in the first example so the problem must be that the header wasn't added. I thought it could be something to do with object scope, but there is a reference to the object so I do not understand why this is the case.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Its strange, looks like the problem lies somewhere else.. can you post the complete code here if possible?

Comment: Very difficult to believe. Impossible, actually. Is this the real code? And why aren't you using an Authenticator?